# Azure Cloud Service host on-premises application server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

Is Azure Cloud Service designed to install and run some custom software, which I expect to be up and running 100% of time, let's say RabbitMQ server or something other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for installing a custom software service like a RabbitMQ queue would be to host it on a [dedicated Azure virtual machine](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/). Due to maintenance and OS patching, a single VM won't provide you 100% uptime, so if that's what you need you'd run it in a distributed set up across two or more VMs configured in an [availability set](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/).

Azure also has its own [queue storage service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) platform which is covered by a 99.9% or greater availability SLA.